# String time complexity

Tags: java, c#, python, string, data-structures

```
public String joinWords(String[] words)
{ 
     String sentence = "";
     for (String w : words)
     {
        sentence = sentence + w;  
     }
     return sentence;
}
```

> Assume that the strings are all the same length (call this x) and that there are n strings.
>   On each concatenation,a new copy of the string is created, and the two strings are copied over,character by character. The  1st iteration requires us to copy x characters. The second iteration requires copying 2x characters. The third iteration requires 3x ,and so on. The total time therefore is O(x + 2x + . . . + nx). This reduces to O(xn^2).

1) I can't understand from the book answer how they get 3x characters in the third iteration , 4x in the 4th iteration . String is immutable and in each sentence variable assignment new String object is created . 
And then is should copy the previous value of the string char by char and the value of w . And i get 2x characters again .
Thank you all !

Comment: You forgot the C++, JavaScript and Scala tags ...

Comment: @Tom, nice comment mate ... really liked it

Answer (score 7):

In the 1st iteration `sentence` has 0 characters and `w` has x characters, so you have to copy x characters.

In the 2nd iteration `sentence` has x characters and `w` has x characters, so you have to copy 2*x characters.

In the 3rd iteration `sentence` has 2*x characters and `w` has x characters, so you have to copy 3*x characters.

In the 4th iteration `sentence` has 3*x characters and `w` has x characters, so you have to copy 4*x characters.

And so on...

Answer (score 2):

`String` itself is immutable but reference is not.

Assume next example:

```
String s = "1";
s = s + "2";
```

`s` will contains value `"12"`, but string `"1"` will not changes.
We can check it in next example:

```
String s = "1";
String sBak = s;
s = s + "2";
```

`s` equal to `"12"` again. And we can check `sBak` to ensure that `"1"` did not changes.

Now back to your sample. Assume that `words = {"first, "second", "third"}`.

Statement `sentence = sentence + w;` updates `sentence` variable. After first iteration it will be `"" + "first"` wich is `"first"`. After second iteration it will be equal to `"first" + "second"` and so on.

So length of string referenced by `sentence` will increase each time (each time `sentence` will point to different string).